# sublime autocompletion from php public static?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have main.php

```
include("DB.php");
```

and in my DB I have some public static function like

```
public static function getOne($table, $where='') {
 }
```

Is there a way I can have an autocomplete in main.php ?
ex: `DB::getOne(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Yarek,
you can try plugin, but in sublime text 3:
https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete

But it works only when DB.php is opened.
For more plugins PHP:
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/sublime-text-3-for-php-developers

Answer (score 0):

if you want sublime to autocomplete you code you first have to install package control from :https://packagecontrol.io/installation
after that install codeintel from :
http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/
and you will be ready to go

Comment: I think the plugin doesn't support exactly autocomplete.

Comment: no, it does support autocomplete , i use it and this is from codeintel on github :
Code intelligence plugin ported from Open Komodo Editor to Sublime Text.

Supports all the languages Komodo Editor supports for Code Intelligence (CIX, CodeIntel2):
Provides the following features:
Jump to Symbol Definition - Jump to the file and line of the definition of a symbol.
Imports autocomplete - Shows autocomplete with the available modules/symbols in real time.
Function Call tooltips - Displays information in the status bar about the working function.

Comment: i didn't write that the plugin doesn't support autocomplete